# HELP!!! Court order for a DMCA counter notice

Tags: copyright, court, lawyer, dmca

I was reposting someone's AI pictures without permission and Twitter removed them so I filled a counter notice saying it's AI.
The next day I got this email from Twitter. What does it mean and what should I do? **I don't want to take it to the court**. **He's from Japan and I'm from Romania.** He has my name and address.

**We’ve received your DMCA counter-notification regarding content recently removed from your account in response to a DMCA takedown notice.
If we don’t receive notice from the complainant within 10 business days that the complainant has filed an action seeking a court order to restrain you from engaging in infringing activity relating to the material on Twitter, we’ll replace or cease disabling access to the material.**

Comment: Law.SE does not provide specific legal advice and can't help you with a particular situation or case.

Comment: What part of the email you didn't understand? It says they will wait for the complainant (the other guy) to take the matter to the courts, otherwise they will restore your post.

Comment: @sourcream i dont want to take it to the court, what should i do?

Comment: That's not up to you to decide. The person who asked for your images to be taken down gets to decide whether they want to escalate to a lawsuit, or do nothing (in which case Twitter will put the images back up).

Comment: @Cadence so what should i do? speak to the person and ask not to take it to court?

Comment: @Gabriel don't overthinking it. If all you want is to avoid a lawsuit, this is very, very unlikely to happen, especially involving AI generated content. You don't need to talk to anyone. And next time, you may want to think more carefully if you really want to appeal a DMCA takedown.

Comment: @sourcream thanks a lot, i feel a lot better now

Comment: "so what should i do? speak to the person and ask not to take it to court?"  Is it a big company that can afford to take you to court or is it some individual who probably can't? (...especially since he's in Japan and nobody else in this story is within a 10-hour flight of Japan!)  Also if he takes the matter to court, you can always just comply with the court order.  If he doesn't, your posts will be restored.

Comment: @phoog it's an individual, i was just reposting his art without permission, i didn't think I'd get an email saying I'll be taken to court over AI pictures, but the others say it's not very likely to be taken to court

Comment: “Ask them to not take me to court” - that was the DMCA notice. They told you “we are not taking you to court if our copyrighted material is removed. A counter notice basically says “come on then, sue me, I’m willing to fight you”. If I was the guy, I’d ask a lawyer how to cause you the maximum amount of financial damage at minimum cost to myself.

Answer (score 1):

### It means what it says

You have allegedly violated the Japanese person's copyright. They can sue you for that if they want. If they tell Twitter within ten days that they have commenced a lawsuit, Twitter will not restore your posts. If they don't, Twitter will restore your posts.

Whether they sue you or not is out of your control. If they do, you need to seek legal advice from a lawyer, not from us, but I can say they your choices then will to do what they have asked in their suit, negotiate a settlement, or defend your position.

Comment: That last sentence is a doozy.